# Не показывает характеристики карточки товара в OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart3.x

Сайт поддерживает 3 языка(русский, английский, грузинский)
Возникла проблема вот в чём

В карточке товара, в грузинской версии отсутствует вкладка Характеристики.
При этом если я переключаю эту страницу на русский или английский язык, то вкладка "Характеристики" видна
(Прикрепил скриншоты)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ЧТО Я ПРЕДПРИНЯЛ...**

Решил посмотреть по коду
и при переключении на грузинскую версию не обнаружил строки кода для характеристик

```
<a href="#tab-specification" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(119, 119, 119); border-color: rgb(119, 119, 119);">Характеристики</a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите пожалуйста в какой файл мне нужно зайти и решить проблему
`view/theme/template/product/product.tpl?` или в другой?

**И В ЗАВЕРШЕНИИ**

-Разработчик шаблона сказал про массивы но не сказал где их искать...
-Все атрибуты и характеристики переведены на 3 языка и админ.панели всё отображается.

**UPDATE**

Залиты 6 файлов из /system/storage/modification

https://dropmefiles.com/kGjaE

Comment: добавьте на какой-нибудь файл-шейр хостинг файлы: catalog\model\catalog\product.php;  controller/product/product.php;  template/product/product.tpl и добавьте ссылки на них в вопрос. Так же проверьте, нет ли в этих файлов в system\storage\modification таких же файлов (возможно они переписаны каким-то расширением, тогда в оригинальных файлах ничего не найдём)

Comment: @KirillKorushkin есть таких 4 файла  system\storage\modification

Тогда получается те файлы, которые вы выше перечислили не заливать на файлшейр хостинг...

Comment: только те, что в modification

Comment: @KirillKorushkin в конце вопроса добавлена ссылка

Answer (score 1):

В `controller/product/product.php` проверьте как формируется массив $data['attribute_groups']. Это и есть характеристики. Дефолтно он должен собираться так (и не должен быть обёрнутый в `if` и т.п.):

```
$data['attribute_groups'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

В template/product/product.tpl найдите строчку `{% if attribute_groups %}`. Должен быть такой вид (ну или примерно такой):

```
     {% if attribute_groups %}
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-specification" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="specification-tab">
           <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                {% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2"><strong>{{ attribute_group.name }}</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{ attribute.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ attribute.text }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: Те файлы написаны на twig, но то что вы указали все фрагменты кода есть.
В 1-ом случае массив создаётся без if , как вы и писали
Что касается 2-ого большого фрагмента кода то так и написано.

colspan = 2, ради эксперимент изменил на 3 но ничего не изменилось.

В самом файле product.php нигде не видно заданного значения массивов, после я посмотрел значения переменных ['product_id'], model_catalog_product ...